# Wolf trip on hit during an attack of opportunity

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat

A wolf gets a free trip attempt on a successful bite attack.  However, this trip attack is a free action, and free actions must be taken on your turn.  Does this mean that if a wolf gets an attack of opportunity, and hits, he doesn't get a trip attempt because it is not his turn?

This makes RAW-sense to me, but not intuitive sense, so I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: This is the same situation as the linked question: can you use a follow-up free action after an AoO? See the linked question.